# Iterate through the Criteria1 array values of AutoFilter

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I've been searching for this for an hour now, and I must not be using the correct terms, because I can't seem to find anything that does what I THINK I need to do.

I have a small data set, ~100 rows x 9 cols.

I already have it filtered by two cols and the resulting data set is down to 8 records.  However, I need to filter one more column based on those 8 records.  How can I iterate through that column's Criteria1 array? (Col A)

I'd like to step through each element and test it...if it passes, keep it, if not...remove it.  However, I cannot seem to figure out how to step through the existing Criteria1's array of values.

I also thought maybe I could use a For loop and step through the filtered rows, but it stepping through all data rows, not the filtered one...

```
index = 1
'Just picked a range that started in the data area and would be past the number of items I need to go through
For i = 6 To 30                    'First row # of filtered data is 13
  If Cells(i, "A") = "" Then
    'Blank Line
    Exit For
  Else
    aTest(index) = Cells(i, "A")
    Debug.Print aTest(index)      'Steps through each row of the unfiltered data, not filtered
    index = index + 1
  End If
Next i
```

Essentially, this is the array of values I need to go through and remove the values that end in 90.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$M$108").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
  Criteria1:=Array("31510", "31605", "31607", "31608", "31690", "81603", _
                   "81604", "81690"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Need someone to point me in the right direction...

Comment: See the Advanced filter https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/2/16/advanced-filters-with-vba-to-automate-filtering-on-and-out-specific-values

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give this a go. The code does the following:

- gets the current visible cells in column A as you only want to take candidates for the `Criteria1` from cells that you can see
- process each cell in that range and apply a test e.g. `Right(val, 2) <> "90"` and store values that pass in an array
- add a new filter to the existing AutoFilter and provide array to the `Criteria1` parameter

HTH

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngFilter As Range
    Dim rngVisibleData As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim varCriteria() As String
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    'quit if no filter
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If Not ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'get visibile cells in column A as candidates for filter
    Set rngVisibleData = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    'process candidates
    lngCounter = 0
    For Each rngCell In rngVisibleData
        If Right(CStr(rngCell.Value), 2) <> "90" Then
            lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
            ReDim Preserve varCriteria(1 To lngCounter)
            varCriteria(lngCounter) = CStr(rngCell.Value)
            Debug.Print rngCell.Value
        End If
    Next rngCell

    'add new filter with processed candidates
    Set rngFilter = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=varCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Comment: That'll work perfectly...I actually need to do more massaging than just ending in 90...but this will get me to at least using the filtered data set.  Thanks!